# Is it possible to copy just highlighted numbers from Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a Tableau workbook that connects to a database and then has several sheets that reorganize the data into different tables and graphs that I need.

If I make a sheet that has 2 rows and 1 field for example, I can't highlight the numbers and just copy them without also copying the row names for each item.

Is there a way I can copy just the numbers, nothing else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not appear to be possible :(

As can be seen from the following Tableau threads:

- [Copy data from Text tables to clipboard](https://community.tableau.com/ideas/4263)
- [Copy single cell from view data](https://community.tableau.com/ideas/1225)

various incarnations of your request have already been asked of the development team that have yet to make it into Tableau. I also couldn't find anything in the [user documents](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/help.htm#save_export_data.html#view_copy_clipboard) that describes a workaround.

There's a way to do this using Python and probably Autohotkey if that's of interest - both options are hackish.